# excel append number to a cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, append

I am trying to make an ascending transaction number of 9 digits.

in cell C1 I have a date (number) as 201510.

In column A6 down I would like to take the right 4 digits of C1 and append 001, and then drag down. So A6 will read 1510001 and A7 1510002, etc.

I have achieved this by typing in A5 000.
Then with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE((RIGHT($C$1, LEN($C$1)-2)),$A5)+1
```

This works in A6, result 1510001 but in A7 it is 15101510002. I can make this simply by adjusting A7 to `=SUM(A6)+1`.

```
=CONCATENATE((RIGHT($C$1, LEN($C$1)-2)),$A$5)+1
```

If I copy this down +1 does not change to +2, etc, anyway to achieve that? And still has that extra number in cell A5 which  I don't like.

I would like a clean formula sat in cell A6 which isn't likely to cause confusion in the future, and hopefully without the extra 000 in cell A5. So A6 can simply be copied down and the formula will follow.

Any ideas for a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=CONCATENATE(RIGHT($C$1,4),TEXT(ROW(A1),"000"))

Also you said that you want 4 right digits whilst in the formula you proposed, there is the date length minus 2. I do not know if it is going to be relevant for you - if yes, change the number 4 to what you used.

Comment: Thanks zaptask, succinct and perfect, it works well and I knew there would be a way. I did use my 'right' formula as sometimes the date has a suffix (when it's the month in progress, for example).  Thank you.